# Codacy: Possible to add patterns for markdown documentation?

Tags: codacy

In our project we are hosting the code at github and placing the documentation in the "docs" directory. We would like to add so-called Codacy "patterns" for the documentation (written in markdown), how can this be done? Is this something that can only be done manually?

Right this is what it looks like for us:

[image: documentation: no pattern]

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: Do you mean templates?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comments, i've updated the question to clarify. Kind Regards, Tord

Comment: @sunyata Codacy is for code review and metrics, it is not a documentation generation tool.

Comment: @Waylan Patterns are what Codacy calls its rules, if you don't know what they are you really should not be critiquing the OP for using the  correct terminology for the tool.

Comment: @MartinSpamer at the time that I made that comment, the question was so vague that I couldn't event guess that "Patterns" were a Codacy specific thing. The more recent updates make that clear, so it seems my comment helped improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment it seems codacy doesn't support markdown files: https://support.codacy.com/hc/en-us/articles/207994735-Supported-Languages

Also, I think Codacy doesn't have Documentation patterns anymore (go to https://www.codacy.com/account/patterns and filter patterns by category: there's no 'documentation' category anymore)